# What is the CSS class for IE in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. I want to know, is there any specific CSS class to define IE browsers into BODY or HTML tag. I want to write CSS specially for All IE browsers.

I know bootstrap provide some CSS class for IE browsers into HTML tag from where we can write version wise CSS but I want to write all a CSS which will be applicable for all IE browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution will be conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE]> <body class="browser-ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> --> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Be aware that this solution will not work with IE10
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Though I got this idea after asking :)